# Execute BCP command in remote server

Tags: sql-server

i am facing an issue while executing the BCP command in the remote server.

i have the following command in a batch file which executes a script file.
The script file process a temporary table and writes the records in temporary table to a file.

```
SQLCMD -SQA_Server236 -dtestdb -Usa -PPassword1  -i"D:\script\Writing to Files\Write to CSV.sql" -o"D:\script\script_logs.log"
```

--script files contains...

```
declare @table    NVARCHAR(255)  
declare @filename VARCHAR(100)  
set @filename='C:\TextFile\abcd.csv'
set @table ='##Indexes_Add'




  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Indexes_Add') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
    DROP TABLE ##Indexes_Add
    END 


 CREATE TABLE  ##Indexes_Add
(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    alter_command NVARCHAR(MAX),
    successfully_readded BIT NULL,
 )

  insert into ##Indexes_Add select 'a',0
  insert into ##Indexes_Add select 'a',0
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..'+@table) IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';


       SELECT @cols += ',' + name
      FROM tempdb.sys.columns
      WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..'+@table)
      ORDER BY column_id;




    SELECT @cols = STUFF(@cols, 1, 1, '');




    SET @sql = N'EXEC master..xp_cmdshell ''bcp "SELECT ''''' 
        + REPLACE(@cols, ',', ''''',''''') + ''''' UNION ALL SELECT ' 
        + 'RTRIM(' + REPLACE(@cols, ',', '),RTRIM(') + ') FROM ' 
       + 'tempdb.dbo.'+@table + '" queryout "' + @filename + '" -c -t, -SQA_Server236 -Usa -PPassword1''';  



  EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
    print @sql

    END
```

My problem-:

When i run the above batch command in a batch file and i give my local server other than server name "QA_Server236" , i am getting the file "abcd.csv" created in my system but when i give the server name as "QA_Server236" the file is created in the remote machine i.e QA_Server236. But i want the file to be created in my system if the given server is a remote server say "QA_Server236"

Can anyone help me in this issue. i am not getting any method to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right BCP does not allow saving result sets and/or logs to remote machines. But you could try to mount a folder on remote PC to a shared folder on your local machine and set the output location there, or maybe try using network path "\[YOURPC]....".
As I'm not sure it works (actually, I think it won't), here's the only solution I can think of: add a line to your batch which moves the file(s) from the remote machine to your PC (xcopy or similar) after BCP finished executing (in batch, do this as "Call bcp.exe [params]" instead of just "bcp.exe ...")
Hope this helps!